# When a team member push to repo my changes become a branch - Sourcetree/Git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When a team member pushes to the repo my changes become a branch. So, in order for me to push, I have to Stash my changes, make a Pull and then Apply Stash. If I try to Pull without Stashing I get a merge error. Any work around this? You know, make a pull and then push my changes without stashing. Not sure what I changed in my setting that is causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is: I need to create a new **Branch**. The only reason I get an error when I try to make a **Pull** is that **git** is avoiding to overwrite my local changes. So, I need to create a branch and after I make a Pull, I do a Merge and then a **Push**. Also, you have the option of doing a **Rebase**. This is an excellent article about [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).